# How to solve 5-4?

Tags: super-meat-boy

What I do is, all while holding the running button:

- Run off the platform and jump
- Jump then hold jump for a little longer to climb that extra height
- Jump off the wall onto the left.
- Jump off the wall onto the right.
- Reach slightly above the first repulser
- Reach slightly above the second repulser
- End up on the wall below Bandage Girl.

[image]

From there I'm stuck. If I try to jump back on the second repulser, I don't gain enough altitude to reach the ledge.

Am I screwing up with the double-repulser jump? Am I supposed to end up on that wall?

I could try using Commander Video's longer jumping capabilities, but with him I can't clear the second repulser jump, as the first doesn't gain him enough height. The other character I have is Headcrab, but it doesn't seem to be particularly useful for anything.

The A+ time is 13.5 and by the time I reach the opposite wall 6.5 seconds have elapsed, so I guess I'm not supposed to reach that ledge straight away after all.  I still can't manage to pull this off however.

Comment: What, no picture? You could get an achievement that way too!

Comment: @Raven I already have that ticket :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick youtube search pulled up the following video, which helps demonstrate what I'm about to tell you you need to do.

Basically, you shouldn't try to reach the wall under bandage girl, as your position on the wall there prevents you from getting enough vertical boost from the repulsor to safely clear the buzz saw. If you jump from the (safe) flat ground *before* the final repulsor, you can easily clear the buzzsaw, as the video shows.

Edit: Okay, now that you've posted a picture, I've misattributed the source wall of your frustrations. In that case, the answer is much simpler -- You're not supposed to end up on that wall. You need to get over the buzzsaw and inside the 2nd building *from* the repulsor.

Comment: If I were on the iPhone I wouldn't be able to see the video. Just saying :)

Comment: @badp - that's why I wrote a paragraph explaining what you should be doing as well.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the above answer, you *can* make it out alive even if you land on the side of the building *(I just did)*.

Just get below the buzzsaw, and jump directly to the right, so you end up above the repulsor.  The repulsor will give you enough vertical push to make it over the buzzsaw.

Comment: I wouldn't say *contrary* so much as *alternatively*.

Comment: @Raven: *"your position on the wall there prevents you from getting enough vertical boost from the repulsor to safely clear the buzz saw."*

Comment: That line is talking about a different repulsor, though. (The one directly below Bandage Girl)